# Convert cronjob to launchctl plist

Tags: macos, cron, launchd

I should convert this cronjob to a launchctl plist.

Is this possible?

```
0 8-18 * * 1-5 /usr/bin/curl -s --data "par1=a&par2=b&press=OK" http://mydomain.com/file.php /dev/null
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically you could save a property list like this as `~/Libary/LaunchAgents/com.superuser.408777.plist`, and load it with `launchctl load ~/Libary/LaunchAgents/com.superuser.408777.plist` or by logging out and back in.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN
http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd >
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.superuser.408777</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>curl</string>
        <string>--data</string>
        <string>par1=a&par2=b&press=OK</string>
        <string>http://mydomain.com/file.php</string>
    </array>
<!--    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/absolute/path/to/script</string> -->
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Weekday</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>8</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Weekday</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>Day</key>
        <integer>9</integer>
    </dict>
<!--    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>3600</integer> --> this would just run the program arguments every hour
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

As far as I know, it's not possible to specify date ranges like hours 8-18 and days 1-5, other than listing each combination individually. You could run an external script every hour and exit it depending on the date though.

```
weekday=$(date +%w)
hour=$(date +%H)
[[ $weekday -le 0 || $weekday -ge 6 || $hour -le 7 || $hour -ge 19 ]] && exit
curl -s --data "par1=a&par2=b&press=OK" http://mydomain.com/file.php /dev/null
```

Comment: Thumbs down to Apple for not supporting commas or dashes for specifying ranges and days. It makes for a very long and difficult plist file. I submitted a feedback report on OSX to Apple over this just now.

Comment: Thumbs down to Apple for not properly supporting a simple industry standard single-line crontab :/